# override short cut keys in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

In google chrome there is a short cut to jump to the next browser tab with `CTRL + TAB`

How to override this short cut?

This doesn't work

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    switch(e.which){
    case 9:
        e.preventDefault();
        break;
    }
});
```

I still want `TAB` to keep its defaults, but not when `CTRL + TAB` is pressed

Comment: Try to bind the keys and u can use event.preventDefault(). i am not sure about this , i am just throwing an idea.

Comment: I think you can't, just like you can't override `Ctrl+F`

Comment: Try $(document).on('keydown', function(e) {})

Comment: Have also tried that.. not working

Comment: You cannot override this behaviour. You'd have better to explain why would you need that?

Comment: Its a single page applikation where I need some short cuts

Comment: @clarkk You should define your custom shortcuts in a way it won't interfering with any native browser ones

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

```
$(window).keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 9)
    {
          e.preventDefault();
          // code
    }
});
```

reference site to see keycode is [here](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html)